# Git clone with passphrase

Tags: git, batch-file

I would like to use 1 command - 'git clone...' but with passphrase using SSH.
Is it possible ? I want to make a script which clone repository so I have to give my passphrase as a parameter. (I cant use ssh-agent)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34169584/341994

Comment: Your question is off topic. This site is for assistance with issues from your provided code attempt at performing a specific task. It is not where you ask for the code to perform that task, which is essentially just research. Please research the task and write the code before asking for assistance with it. We have an excellent search facility at the top of each page, which should provide you with sufficient code for you to adapt into that code attempt yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple batch file

**ssh_ask.bat**

```
@echo off
echo [my-passphrase]
```

Then you have to set two variables (usefull in another batch file)
**prepare.bat**

```
set display=0
set "SSH_ASKPASS=C:\\path\\to\\ssh_ask.bat"
```

Now ssh will ask the batch file for the passphrase

Comment: to be honest I don't undestand, so this is 1 file with 4 line of code ? or 2 file ? where i should 'git clone' and in which order ?

Comment: @discCard I edited my post, trying to be more clear

Comment: ok,thanks, so we have 2 file, but in which of this 2 file i should put line with 'git clone' ?

Comment: @discCard You don't need to put `git clone` into the batch files. Just start the `prepare.bat` once. After that, yxou can use git clone from the console without asking for the passphrase

Comment: after run prepare.bat I'm still getting ask for passphrase :( 
What is SSH_ASKPASS ? this is system variable ? I don't understand why this should works

Comment: @discCard With the SSH_ASKPASS variable, the ssh program knows that it should start the program in the SSH_ASKPASS variable instead of asking the user (only when the DISPLAY variable is also set). Did you modify the `C:\\path\\to\\ssh_ask.bat` to YOUR real path?

Comment: yes, I wrote my true path to ssh_ash.bat  and i still have to ask passphrase by cmd

Comment: maybe i should also add somewhere "SSH_ASKPASS" variable in system ?

Comment: it is windows 10

Comment: @discCard If you use `ssh target-host` the ssh_ask.bat should be started, if not (if the `SSH_ASKPASS` is wrong) you should see errors like `CreateProcessW failed error:2
ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory`. You could test that. If you get `Permission denied, please try again.` your user/passphrase is wrong

Comment: i wrote it in git bash and i got error: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname target-host: Name or service not known" and when i wrote it in cmd i got: " 'ssh is not recognized as an internal command' "